# How to Optimize the parameter

Tags: java, oop, selenium-webdriver, automation, parameter-passing

I have to pass so many arguments in my method,So kindly suggest me how to optimize these params.

How to optimize these params so my code will look clean and efficients

// below is the code.

```
public class ContactPage extends BasePage {

WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[text()='Contact Information']")
WebElement contactPageHeader;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='contactForm']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select")
WebElement title;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id = 'first_name']")
WebElement firstName;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id = 'middle_initial']")
WebElement middleName;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id = 'surname']")
WebElement lastName;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='text' and @name='nickname']")
WebElement nickName;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='client_lookup']")
WebElement company;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='company_position']")
WebElement position;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='department']")
WebElement department;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='contact_lookup_sup']")
WebElement supervisor;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='text' and @name='contact_lookup_ref']")
WebElement referredBy;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='mobile']")
WebElement mobile;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='email']")
WebElement email;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='im_id']")
WebElement messengerId;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id='skype_id']")
WebElement skypeId;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='text' and @name='identifier']")
WebElement identifier;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='text' and @name='address_title']")
WebElement addressTitle;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@id= 'tags']")
WebElement tags;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='contactForm']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/input[2]")
WebElement save;

public ContactPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

public boolean verifyContactPageHeader() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Constants.DEFAULT_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(contactPageHeader));
    return contactPageHeader.isDisplayed();

}

public void createNewContact(String FirstName, String MiddleName, String LastName, String Nickname, String Company,
        String Position, String Department, String Supervisor, String ReferredBy, String Mobile, String Email,
        String MessengerID, String SkypeID, String Identifier, String AddressTitle, String tags,
        String Description) {

}
```

Only seeking the code optimization for my given piece of codes in above block.

Comment: You could create a class that will store this parameters as own fields. And then with a help of IDE generate `Builder` for this class to create objects easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a Contact class with all the values you are passing to createNewContact() as fields, and getter methods for each one
2. Apply a builder pattern to that class as seen
   [here](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern)
3. Refactor createNewContact() to take a Contact object as argument, and use the getter methods to extract the values from the Contact object